# MS Graph API copy folder of shared folder into the same parent won't copy subfolders and files

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Last month I setup a Microsoft Services integration in my angular web app to access the company's **personal account** onedrive. So we use `MSAL` as the authentication service and the `MSAL_INTERCEPTOR` from `msal-angular` to authenticate our requests. All employees have the company's onedrive as a shared drive. Everything was working fine, but this week I received feedback that the model folder that should be copied with a new name isn't creating the subfolders and files.

Let me show my workflow to copy the model folder in the same parent folder with another name:

1. Get the model folder's metadata and save the parent info:

```yaml
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/SHARED_DRIVE_ID/items/SHARED_DRIVE_ID!52853:/05-DRM/01-Em%20Andamento/ORC-000_ANO-NOME%20DO%20CONTRATO-GESTOR

response:
{
  ...
  "id": "SHARED_DRIVE_ID!110649",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-05-21T15:28:55.567Z",
  "name": "ORC-000_ANO-NOME DO CONTRATO-GESTOR",
  "size": 0,
  "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/f/s!ABM9Mjoi6dy8huA5",
  ...
  "parentReference": {
    "driveId": "SHARED_DRIVE_ID",
    "driveType": "personal",
    "id": "SHARED_DRIVE_ID!95075",
    "name": "01-Em Andamento",
    "path": "/drives/SHARED_DRIVE_ID/items/SHARED_DRIVE_ID!52853:/05-DRM/01-Em%20Andamento"
  },
  "fileSystemInfo": { "createdDateTime": "2021-02-11T13:47:04Z", "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-03-29T13:50:23.99Z" },
  "folder": {
    "childCount": 8,
    "view": { "viewType": "thumbnails", "sortBy": "takenOrCreatedDateTime", "sortOrder": "ascending" }
  },
  "shared": { "scope": "users", "owner": { "user": { "displayName": "Nortan Diretores", "id": "SHARED_DRIVE_ID" } } }
}
```

2. Make the copy request using the "parentReference"

```yaml
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/SHARED_DRIVE_ID/items/SHARED_DRIVE_ID!52853:/05-DRM/01-Em%20Andamento/ORC-000_ANO-NOME%20DO%20CONTRATO-GESTOR:/copy

payload:
{
  "parentReference": { "driveId": "SHARED_DRIVE_ID", "id": "SHARED_DRIVE_ID!95075" },
  "name": "ORC-189_2021-Posto de Combustível 3M-Nichollas Gomes"
}

response:
Status Code: 202 Accepted
```

3. The newly copied folder is created with all subfolders and files of the model folder.
4. After four seconds of the copy request been accepted(Since there is no way to be notified of the copy process), I get the information of the new folder to get the web URL.

This workflow is working in my test on employee personal onedrive folders, and it was working with our shared folder too. But now, in the shared folder, when we reach step 4 of our workflow, only an empty new folder is created.

Trying to understand what is happening, I also noticed that when it made the copy request on the onedrive website is showed a copy operation that fails sometime later with the following error: `Error: Try again or refresh page`, but I can't debug this error. There is a way to debug this error?

**Edit 1:**
I tried step 2 outside my web app with `Postman` and the same problem happened.

**Edit 2:**
Request response made with postman:

```json
Staus: 202Accepted    Time: 1596 ms    Size: 719 B

{
  "Date": "Sat, 22 May 2021 16:46:16 GMT",
  "Cache-Control": "no-store",
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
  "Location": "https://df.api.onedrive.com/v1.0/monitor/4s7kSj8n8-eF7gyNg40BOOKlQvmxjiQ9Yvana5Jl1l87mCOs4AGis4lO95DtmZaccjg-teKUNaY5EQtMya2RnjHfVY7DDbNXgCMYrQju89nzRdbwORmMhSxoy6mds4QfFOmAF92vSB7JL3J2456uxirjwjE3KCkN3KC9TfrJcxvGtFQU1VT7Euk6WMpoq3HeRcOwCtEP1GWuegI3qo1jFSj8PKoyIvTMrZ43snVoiBmjupBHiDlnTUsLkWzqUZ5v1X",
  "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
  "request-id": "3a02e7bd-dbac-48e6-9a62-939ce0f2e3e0",
  "client-request-id": "3a02e7bd-dbac-48e6-9a62-939ce0f2e3e0",
  "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": {
    "ServerInfo": {
      "DataCenter": "Brazil South",
      "Slice": "E",
      "Ring": "3",
      "ScaleUnit": "000",
      "RoleInstance": "CP1PEPF00001A64"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: (1) what you meant by company's personal onedrive - if i am not wrong you're talking about OneDrive for business provided by company per employee? (2) Share the Graph API error from the response, along with requestid, timestamp (either from postman or your application)

Comment: I believe you are aware that in most of the cases the copy action is performed asynchronously. The response from the API will only indicate that the copy operation was accepted or rejected, say due to the destination filename already being in use. So its worth to check you're not endup in the above scenario.

Comment: (1) No. I'm talking about personal OneDrives. The company has a personal account as each employee has one. For us in South America is too expensive to pay for OneDrive business account. (2) This is the point, there is no error. As I said, the request is accepted, the new folder is created in the right place, but somehow there is an internal error while copying the folder files. I will update my question with the requested information

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this point. My scenario is to copy a base folder to a new folder without name conflict in the same parent folder. When I try the same operation in my personal OneDrive folder it works as expected, but in the company shared folder I have this problem

Comment: @Dev any news after I provided the requestID?

Comment: Ok, i looked at the above stack trace. I see that you got HTTP 202 which was expected in case if the API call successfully worked. Also i see that it contains the Location header,  provides a URL for a service that will return the current state of the copy operation. You can use this [info to determine when the copy has finished](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/long-running-actions-overview). Since the API call is not failed, its tough to comment what went wrong. Also i see the above error which is not coming from Graph, rather from your app. Try repro issue using POSTMAN/Graph Explorer

Comment: @Dev, I finally found the problem. I posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what was the problem. The copy endpoint doesn't handle relative paths using an item as a base path like:

```yaml
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/SHARED_DRIVE_ID/items/SHARED_DRIVE_ID!52853:/05-DRM/01-Em%20Andamento/ORC-000_ANO-NOME%20DO%20CONTRATO-GESTOR:/copy
```

So, I just changed in my workflow the copy endpoint using the item ID that I got when getting the folder metadata to get the parent info. Now my copy request is:

```yaml
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/SHARED_DRIVE_ID/items/SHARED_DRIVE_ID!110649/copy
```

After this change my copy operation monitor result is:

```yaml
{
    "errorCode": "",
    "operation": "itemCopy",
    "percentageComplete": 100.0,
    "resourceId": "SHARED_DRIVE_ID!290908",
    "status": "completed",
    "statusDescription": "Completed 10/10 files; 15906/15906 bytes"
}
```

Instead,

```yaml
{
    "errorCode": "",
    "operation": "itemCopy",
    "percentageComplete": 0.0,
    "status": "notStarted",
    "statusDescription": "Completed 0/0 files; 0/0 bytes"
}
```

Thanks @Dev for all your support.

Comment: Glad to hear back @Kikuto!! Thanks for posting the resolution back to the community and upvoted it :)